# Code Combat not interacting locally

Tags: macos

I wanted to install Code Combat locally to be also able to understand it better. I have followed the steps (for Mac OSX, I have Yosemite) described at: https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/wiki/Developer-environment

Everything worked. I have all the scripts running, without problems, mongo is up and running, the game is starting, but then, the game itself can't be proceeded.

I haven't restored the mongo dump, which is 2GB fat and which I can't download easily with my current internet connection, but it seems to be optional.

Looking on the console, I have a couple 404 that I can't explain, see below. If somebody could help me to get the game running locally, I would be very grateful.

```
GET /db/thang.type/529ffbf1cf1818f2be000001/version 404
GET /db/level/dungeons-of-kithgard/session 404
```

As well as the mp3 files, which I am fine not to have.

Thanks in advance,
Matthieu

PS: I would have liked to specify more tags, but as it concerns many languages and doesn't have a specific tag, I didn't know which one to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's mandatory to have a mongo dump to have the base elements for the levels. But 2GB is too much and a solution will attempt to be found to be able to export only the required data. 200MB should be enough

UPDATE: With the following ticket being implemented, the size is reduced to less than 100MB: https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/issues/1988